# Chain database links to get from X to Y via B,F,G

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry to ask a very general question on here, might be the wrong place, but the answers on here are great so I'm giving it a try.

I have a MYSQL database,
  1 table of geographical features.
  1 table of where operators fly to between two points

```
 |Flyings company|Point A|Point B|

  |Company ID    |A ID   | B ID  |
```

What would be the easiest way to to search how to mix and match your way from point X to point Y? If you have to go X to B, B to F, F to G, G to Y. Open to any suggestions understand if this question gets closed.

Comment: Can you change the schema/add new tables?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you do need graph algorithms. Practically, if you iterate by the number of legs and are willing to limit it by some reasonable number, you can try to use self join queries:

One leg routes:

```
   select leg1.company, leg1.a_id, leg1.b_id 
   from flights leg1 
   where leg1.a_id=1 and leg1.b_id=2
```

Two leg routes:

```
   select leg1.company, leg1.a_id, leg1.b_id, leg2.company, leg2.b_id 
   from flights leg1 join flights leg2 on leg1.b_id=leg2.a_id 
   where leg1.a_id=1 and leg2.b_id=2
```

Three leg routes:

```
   select leg1.company, leg1.a_id, leg1.b_id, leg2.company, leg2.b_id, leg3.company, leg3.b_id 
   from flights leg1 join flights leg2 on leg1.b_id=leg2.a_id join flights leg3 on leg2.b_id join leg3.a_id 
   where leg1.a_id=1 and leg3.b_id=2
```

And so on, up to your limit.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to build a directed graph using your data. Nodes would match geographical points, and edges would match operations between two points

Then you proceed to find all paths between the two arbitrary nodes you want.

This is not a problem you can solve just with a database query: you will have to load all (maybe not at once, but eventually) the data in order to build the complete graph and provide a complete list of answers.

Comment: All very well and good, but doesn't exactly explain how to store or search such a graph using the tools tagged in the question.

Comment: Finding all paths between two nodes in a directed graph is a solved problem. You can look up many implementations in any language you choose. I decided to point the OP into the right direction, instead of interpreting this as a 'please code it for me' type of question.

Comment: Thanks this is a new direction for me. I'll do some reading and come back to it.